# How to link two object files

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

I have rfact.s and rfactmain.c

rfact.s:

```
    .text
.p2align 4
.global rfact
.type rfact, @function

rfact:
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
pushl   %ebx
subl    $4, %esp
movl    8(%ebp), %ebx
movl    $1, %eax
cmpl    $1, %ebx
jle     .L53

leal    -1(%ebx), %eax
movl    %eax, (%esp)
call    rfact
imull   %ebx, %eax


.L53:
addl    $4, %esp
popl    %ebx
popl    %ebp
ret
```

rfactmain.c:

```
int main(){
   int x = rfact(4);
   return 0;
}
```

I am on a 64 bit system. So first I get both object files by doing

```
gcc -m32 -c rfact.s
gcc -m32 -c rfactmain.c
```

then i try to link them together like so

```
gcc -m32 -o rf rfact.o rfactmain.o
```

but I get an error

```
gcc -m32 -o rf rfact.o rfactmain.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib64/libc.a when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If i remove the -m32 i get the error (which is expected since both object files are 32 bit)

```
gcc -o rf rfact.o rfactmain.o
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `rfact.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `rfactmain.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have the 32 bit support stuff installed. You probably need the gcc-multilib package or the 32 bit library packages individually. Consult your distro's documentation and/or package manager.